# Track Redis Key changes from Laravel App and Show in Dashboard

Tags: laravel, redis

Scenario:

Redis key **device:alarming** holds the set of devices in alarming state.
Another application is pushing the device id to this set( i don't have control over this independent application).
I have to show the Device List to a Dashboard (through a laravel based application).

I am looking for a solution to accomplish the following:

1. Laravel Application keeps track of Redis Key changes (in this case, the key is a SET)
2. Every time there are changes in the set (the Redis Key), the Laravel App updates the changes in Dashboard.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What about [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor). Have you tried it, if so, what were the challenges you faces etc. Please elaborate with your experience. By the way, welcome.

Comment: hey @vahdet appreciate it. in my understanding monitor is something for debugging, it shows every command ran. While, I need to know if a certain "key" is changed. Do you know of any way around to give me this using Monitor?

Comment: Can you use a cron task and just sweep the key with `Redis::get('device:alarming');`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not sure if I can cron it in real-time, have to check.